# BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded (chat client-server java)

Tags: java

I'm trying to realize a chat client-server (in local) that permits to exchange text and files. I utilize java.security and java.crypto to implement hybrid cryptography (and the tool Swing).
I implemented text exchange and it works fine, now I'm trying to implement file transfer with AES-128 cryptography.
The encrypt method takes in input a selected file chosed by a FileChoser,then it takes file's bytes and inserts them in a byte array.After with "cipher2" I encrypt these bytes and as a result of "cipher2.doFinal" I take byte[] fileBytes. Finally I write "fileBytes" in File file.

```
public File encryptFile(File file) throws  BadPaddingException,IllegalBlockSizeException,NoSuchPaddingException,NoSuchAlgorithmException,InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {


      cipher2 = null;
    byte[] encfile=null;
    byte[] fileBytes=new byte[(int) file.length()];
    cipher2=Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");//creo il cifrario cipher2 con le specifiche riportate
    cipher2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,aesKey,new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes()));//inizializzo il cifrario specificando la chiave di cifratura
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream buf=new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    buf.read(fileBytes,0,fileBytes.length);
    encfile=cipher2.doFinal(fileBytes);//creo il messaggio cifrato
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, encfile);//file (that is selectedFile) results not encrypted in his path
   File ff=new File("C:/Users/ferdinando/Desktop/ciaocript/" + file.getName()); //ff result encrypted in ciaocript
     FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(ff, encfile);
    fis.close();
    buf.close();
       return file;
```

}

After I send the encrypted file in a serialized way thanks ObjectOutputStream's method writeObject():

```
public void sendFile(){
       try{


    sOutput.writeObject( encryptFile(selectedFile));
    jTextArea1.append("File inviato" + "\n");

    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
    System.out.println("Errore nell'invio del file " + ioe.getMessage());

    }
       catch(InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | NoSuchPaddingException e ){
   System.out.println(" Errore nell'invio del file" + e.getMessage());
  }

  }
```

On the other side, server verifies if the object is a File object and if this is true it decrypted file in this way:

```
public void decryptFile(File encfs){

    ServerDecryptCipher = null;

    try {
        byte[] fileBytes;
        byte[] encBytes=new byte[(int) encfs.length()];
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(encfs);
        BufferedInputStream buf=new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        buf.read(encBytes,0,encBytes.length);
        ServerDecryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
    ServerDecryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, AESKey, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes()));
    fileBytes = ServerDecryptCipher.doFinal(encBytes);
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(receivedFile, fileBytes);
        File saveFile=new File(path+"/"+ receivedFile.getName());
       save(receivedFile,saveFile);
        TextAreaChat.append("File ricevuto: "+ receivedFile.getName() + "\n");


    } catch(IOException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | NoSuchPaddingException | NullPointerException e) {
    e.getCause();
    e.printStackTrace();
    TextAreaEventiLog.append("INFO: Errore nella decrittografia del file ricevuto dal client. Errore:"  + e.getMessage() + "\n");
}
}
```

Comment: Your posted code doesn't show how you get the ciphertext from client to server; transmitting a `java.io.File` object does NOT do that. Assuming you do, make sure that the bytes being decrypted are _exactly_ the bytes resulting from encryption; in particular you read the server file into a 4096-byte buffer and then decrypt all of that buffer; if the file didn't contain exactly 4096 bytes, this decrypts something different from the file contents, which will fail in the manner you report.

Comment: I edited my previous question with corrections, @dave_thompson_085 , thanks, now file transer seems to work fine,there isn't errors in console, but when I insert in selectedFile the  encrypted bytes , in the path (where the selectedFile is stored) appears selectedFile not encrypted. If I create new file with same name of selectedFile and I write in it encrypted bytes, it appears encrypted. Why?

Comment: I'm unable to follow what is what in your comment, but in your edited code, as I said before, sending a `java.io.File` object through an `ObjectStream` does NOT send the contents of the file. Are these actually on the same machine or otherwise the same filesystem(s)? If so there is no point in making them separate programs; just write a single program that encrypts a file and then decrypts that file, and then if you have a problem at least you can post a complete example (MCVE).